# Absolute paths in PhoneGap

Tags: url, cordova

My situation is the following:
I have an index.html and some JavaScript that loads HTML snippets from the server. Inside these snippets, I have some URLs to images like 
`/some/folder/picture.jpg`

Of course these do not work in PhoneGap. Weinre tells me that PhoneGap is trying to load the picture from
`file:///some/folder/picture.jpg`

Any ideas how to solve this? I was thinking about something like a base href, or some configuration in PhoneGap where one could specify a root path, but I did not find anything like that ...

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: Are those images loaded on the device or are they on the server?

Comment: You'll have to use an absolute URL for files on the server (`http://www.myserver.com/some/folder/picture.jpg`).

Comment: @Simon On the website, I want to load the images from the server. On the phone, I want to load the images locally.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem especially when you have a lot of views (pages) and want to load one from a menu, yet you are at an unknown location.

The simple work around is to use the window.location object.

```
window.location.href.split('www')[0] + 'www'
```

This gives you the absolute URL to your 'base'. The www is the folder which is relevant for IOS and Android, so this also makes your app compatible in multiple platforms.

From this you can use a regular expression which passes the entire doc like jquery mobile does with data-* attributes to describe their elements. You simply replace the regular expression with the path returned. You'll want to do this during initialisation otherwise it will create a massive bottle neck.

Hope this helps and is along the lines of what you're looking for.

Cheers,

Sententia

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with a `<base>` because `/` is always host-relative — it can't be redefined to be in a subdirectory. You have two options:

- rewrite your HTML to use fully relative paths like `../../some/folder/picture.jpg` (or have something do the rewrite for you as a build step), or
- alter the "browser" (PhoneGap's wrapper) so that it loads URLs differently.

I'm not familiar with PhoneGap so I can't comment on automatic options, but I personally would start using relative URLs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In the meantime, I implemented the following solution:
- use <base> and image URLs relative to that on the website
- rewrite all (absoute) image paths in CSS etc. for PhoneGap